# ajax + php + mysql: (another) issue with charsets

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, character-encoding

I'm having a problem with charset and I'm driving crazy to find the solution. This is what I have:

- I have a MySQL database with 'latin1_spanish_ci' as a collation for the database, the table and each one of the fields.
- An html file with the header '<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">' wich has a form. When the button is pushed, an Ajax is called which sends a POST request to an PHP.
- The PHP with the call 'header('Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');' at the top. This PHP makes a query to the database to get a list of data.
- The AJAX call is the following:

  $.ajax({
  url:"llistat.php",
  type: "POST",
  data:
  {
  sector : $("#sector").val(), 
  cp : $("#cp").val(), 
  province : $("#province").val(), 
  free : $("#free").val() 
  },
  success:
  function(data) {
  $("#results").html("");
  $("#results").append(data);
  },
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-1"
  });

The problem...

1. If I keep the charset header in the PHP, the characters are get properly from the database, but the 'estrange' characters (accents, 'ñ', ...) sent through the AJAX call are not got properly.
2. If I remove the charset header I have the same problem but the other way around. The characters from the call are get properly, but not the ones from the database.
3. Finally if I don't do the call through the Ajax call and I do it straight form submitting the form, everything works properly. The characters are sent properly and the info from the database as well.

What is wrong with all this process? I guess (according to the last point) that there is a difference between calling through an AJAX call or through a submit in the form. But, which is that difference? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.ajax` uses `encodeURIComponent` which always uses UTF-8. What's wrong with your process is not using UTF-8 everywhere.

If you can't change that fact by now, you can `mb_convert_encoding` the ajax data to convert from UTF-8 to Windows-1252 on server side.

Note that:

- To browsers ISO-8859-1 means Windows-1252
- To MySQL latin1 means Windows-1252
- To any PHP function ISO-8859-1 means ISO-8859-1
- For anything except MySQL, Windows-1252 means Windows-1252

Comment: thanks !! that solved my problem !! I pass through `mv_convert_encoding` all the parameters and that solves the problem !

A bit mess all this charset stuff... In the meantime I'll try to change everything to UTF-8.

Comment: @Morillas Yes but it's not recommended, you will have to remember to place `mb_convert_encoding` in some places in the code and not in some other places... it gets very messy and unmaintainable to everyone. For example `json_*` only works with UTF-8 too. It is much much easier to just use UTF-8 everywhere and everything will just work.

Comment: @Morillas if you are going with UTF-8 then the most common mistakes are forgetting to set the text editor to save files in UTF-8 and not setting database *connection* encoding (`mysql_set_charset("utf8")`) which is different from *storage* encoding (the charsets set in SQL config and tables/columns/databases).